# Функция внутри функции?

Tags: c++, qt

Изучаю QT методом "с разбега в лоб" и заметил необычную (для меня) странность. Допустим, мы хотим извлечь строку из элемента QLineEdit:

```
Qstring msg;
msg=ui->lineEdit->text();
```

Как я понимаю, text() это функция-член, к которой мы обращаемся через объект класса с помощью спецификатора "->"  (QT аналог точки для обращения к членам?), но если вдруг нам захотелось предварительно перевести буквы в нижний регистр:

```
msg=ui->lineEdit->text().toLower();
```

Что это? Обращение к функции-члену функции-члена?

Comment: В языке C++ есть два вида обращения в полям и методам объекта, через сам объект(оператор `.`) и через указатель на него(оператор `->`). Оператор стрелка говорит, что вы работаете с указателями.

Comment: Почитайте про [method chaining](http://habrahabr.ru/post/215059/)(не уверен, что там хорошо расписано, но это первая ссылка в гугле, на русском языке, по теме)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Результатом работы метода text() является объект класса QString, для которого вы вызываете метод toLower().

Вы обращаетесь **к результату работы** метода класса.

Comment: Что-то типа cout << v1 << v2? Сначала оператор срабатывает для (cout,v1) а потом для результата работы первого оператора и v2?

Comment: Да, как-то похоже